# How do I get access to the Space Mirrors?

Tags: lore, world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

It's well established in World of Darkness, that the technocracy has an array of space mirrors, not too dissimilar from [Icarus](https://jamesbond.fandom.com/wiki/Icarus) from James Bond: Die Another Day. There is one very prominent use of this device at its full potential:

> They will use their space mirrors as a giant plot device to fight the [Ravnos Antediluvian](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70390/was-the-ravnos-antediluvian-a-wight?noredirect=1&lq=1). It's right before the whole world goes haywire and after a couple of spirit-enhanced nuclear devices had no effect on him. [It's use glasses over a chunk of India but also destroys Ravnos](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134888/30306).

Is there a note which Merit, Background, and/or combination of Spheres regulates access to this device, and which branch of the Technocracy controls its use?

Comment: This stack seems to frown upon answers that cannot be substantiated with sources, therefore I can only give some guidance: I'm fairly certain there isn't that much information outside of Time of Thin Blood. But I cannot be 100% sure because I've not read all the new Technocracy books - I suspect *if* there is an answer, it would be in one of those.

Answer (score 2):

#### Wonder 4, or Forces 4/Correspondence 4.

According to M20 *How Do You DO That?* p. 32:

> Correspondence 4/ Forces 4 may open a gate between a location where sunlight is and one where sunlight is not. This, of course, is vulgar magick, but the sunlight in question is totally real.

Focusing and amplifying this sunlight into a damaging beam would further require a damaging Forces 2 effect, which could be combined with the above effect. If a Mage has the dots in these Spheres, then they can simply cast this effect without needing a formalized Wonder to do so, and if they're a Technocrat with the Devices and Gadgets Tool in their Focus, they could justify it as calling in the orbital doom laser mirrors.

Since this is an effect that requires 4 dots in a Sphere, it would require a 4-dot Wonder to replicate this effect. Acquiring access to this Wonder would require either purchasing the Wonder merit directly, or being a member of the Technocratic Union and requisitioning, borrowing, or politely asking other Technocrats for access to the orbital doom laser mirrors. The rules for these processes are covered on pp. 302-303 of the M20 corebook.

Comment: Do note that the space mirrors are not a W20 item but only appear in the Time of Judgement supplements. As such, this is possibly correct in what *could* be this, but speculative: It's not just *one* attack roll, the space mirrors I talk about glass over a whole city in an instant.